# Parameter list in the procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a procedure A with 2 parameters and this procedure is called in 10 stored procedures.(b,c,d....)
Now proc A is updated with 3 parameters , is there any way to update proc A parameters list in calling 10 procs in a single go.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No..You need to change the definition of the procedure in all the 10 other calling procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you publish your API (for example a package specification with several procedures and functions) and it is put into use, you have signed a contract of sorts with other developers.

You should not change the signature of those subprograms (change the terms of the contract) unless absolutely necessary.

Alternatives include:

- When adding a new IN parameter, always put it at the end of the existing parameter list and provide a default value that reflects current (pre-change) behavior. All existing invocations of the subprogram remain valid.
- If your are adding OUT or IN OUT parameters, consider leaving the current subprogram as is, and instead adding an overloading - same name but with the new, expanded parameter list.

This way, the existing code is not invalidated. You can then notify developers about the new subprograms (change to the contract) and they can choose to use them or not.

You can use PL/Scope, by the way, to find all usages of a particular subprogram. LiveSQL.oracle.com offers a number of PL/Scope scripts. Just search for "scope". Also, Philipp Salvisberg offers a great PL/Scope utility on Github: https://www.salvis.com/blog/2017/03/17/plscope-utils-utilities-for-plscope-in-oracle-database-12-2/

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a few procedures will update 3rd statement, you'd use default value for your parameter. So you dont have to update all 10 procedures.

For ex,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_UPD_MYPROCEDURE
( 
   p_ParameterOne IN NUMBER, 
   p_ParameterTwo IN VARCHAR2, 
   p_ParameterThree IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

so when you call your procedure like (without third parameter),

```
PRC_UPD_MYPROCEDURE(1234,'EXAMPLE');
```

is valid.